# Client Side Validation for Blank Fields?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Is there any way to trigger client side jQuery validation when the user enters a textbox and then tabs or clicks out without entering data?  About the only way I can get this to fire is when there's a postback to the server and the server validation kicks in.

Looked around but couldn't find anything.

Thanks

This is what I'm trying

```
$('#firstName input').blur(function () {
        if (!$(this).val()) {
            $(this).addClass('input-validation-error');
        }
    });
```

Tried this too...no luck

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#firstName').keyup(function(event) {
            var input = $(this);
            var message = $(this).val();
            console.log(message);
            if (message) {
                input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
            } else {
                alert('ERROR');
            }
        });
    });
```

For those that might have this issue, this worked for me and it was the cleanest solution

```
$("input").focusout(function() {                
            if (!$(this).val()) {
                $(this).valid();
            }

        });
```

Comment: I think you're going to have to look some more, then come back with your code, explain what didn't work, how did you try to fix it, and post a demo to reproduce the issue. Good luck.

Comment: Yeah, you can use `Regex`

Comment: there are no end of tutorials and plugins for this....you simply haven't done much research

Comment: Will do guys.  Been working on a solution recently but when I tab out it doesn't change the class.  I tried adding a class when there isn't a value but for some reason it won't fire.
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
input=$(this);
var is_name=input.val();
if(!is_name){input.addClass("input-validation-error");}
});
</script>

for some reason it wont do my typical validation on the page.

Answer (score 2):

this is tested just replace the path of the script

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <p><input type="text" id="textbox" value="" /></p>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#textbox").focusout(function () {
                //do your validation here
             if (this.value == '') {
                alert('you should enter text here');
            }
        });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I modified this and it worked for me.  I would accept this as an answer but I wanted to give people exaclty what I did instead.  Thanks again man.

Answer (score 0):

Try using some jquery plugin like [JQuery Validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/) instead of working on small code snippets like this.

Your code should look like this after importing the plugin.

```
    $("#registration_form").validate({ // your form id
        errorLabelContainer: $("div.register-status"), // your error label div
        wrapper: 'li', //error wrapper
        rules: { //the rules for your dom elements
        first_name: {required: true, minlength: 2},
        last_name: {required: true, minlength: 2}
        },
        messages: { //validation messages
            first_name: {required: "Please enter your first name", minlength: "Your first name is not long enough."},
            last_name: {required: "Please enter your last name", minlength: "Your last name is not long enough."}
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) { //your submit ajax handler
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url:  registerurl,
                data: $(form).serialize(),
                success:function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)  { 
                    $("div.register-status").hide().fadeIn().html(responseText);    
                    if(responseText=="success"){
                        $("div.register-status").hide().fadeIn().html("Please wait..."); 
                        $("#registration_form").clearForm();
                    }
                },
                error: function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)  { 
                    $("div.register-status").hide().fadeIn().html(responseText); 
                } 
             });            
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: I'm already including jquery.validate.js into my page and using the client side validation.  I'm going to try to add this code and see what happens.  I assume this is the same plugin?

Comment: Thought about this for a few mins and decided this is double work.  I'm already setting the server side validation requirements from my AccountViewModel class, why duplicate this information in the View itself?  Also I would have to duplicate the validation rules.

Comment: Found a better and simpler validation soliution.  Will post it when it lets me.